# Share variables between two MATLAB m-files executing separately

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, share, workspace, job-scheduling

I'd like to know if there is something like pointers in MATLAB. 
I have two matlab routines which execute simulataneously (that is they are lunched together and run on the same machine, which is, therefore, synchronized in terms of time-stamps). 
The first routine, A, has a parfor loop where a data vector is continuously updated. The second routine, B, needs to get access to a specific (but variable in time) row of the vector (of routine A) and do further calculation.
My first guess is to print the updating rows of routine A in a txt file and then get access to it in B when necessary. However, this will result in a large amount of waste time.
I know that this could be related to parallel jobs and scheduler but I dont know how to implement it.
Thank you for any help, guesses or solutions.

Comment: What mechanism are you using to run these routines simultaneously?

Comment: I havent found anything good yet.

Comment: I spoke with a friend and he redirected me to MPI parallelization paradigms. Basically there should be a way to allocate the process A on a Cpu and B on a different Cpu. A runs in an infinitive loop, and produces the vector A initialized as a global, so that can be shared by B. Another way is to code the process B with lab sender and lab receiver so tgat whe it reaches specific conditions it takes data from A. What do you think about it? Is there anyone who can help me to figure it out in MATLAB coding? Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Probably this [code](http://smlv.cc.gatech.edu/2010/08/27/shared-memory-in-matlab/) will help you, if i got correctly your problem. I am waiting for further comments.
Best wishes!